# How to check whether two objects have the same values in Java?

Tags: java

I have two objects of the same class. The class is containing so many other objects with different types like List<>, ...

What is the best way to determine if this two have the same values? I'm trying to use hashcode function but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
public class MyClass{
   List<OtherClass> myList;
   String foo;
   SubClass mySubClass;

   public MyClass(values...){ ... }
   ...
}

MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(values...);
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(values...); // same values with obj1

if(obj1.hashcode() == obj2.hashcode()){
    System.out.println("This is what I want");
}else{
    System.out.println("This is what happens");
}
```

Comment: Never use `hashCode()` to check for equality. Use `obj1.equals(obj2)`. You'll have to implement them though. Also, keep in mind Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Override `equals()` method in your class with whatever logic you see fit.

Comment: You have to override `equals()` as others have indicated, but much more importantly you have to decide what it means for two objects to be "equal".  A strict "deep equal" would mean comparing the values of all the members, and the values contained in the members out to the very ends of the object graph.  Maybe that's not what you want, but only you can decide what "equals" means.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you override `equals()` you should _also_ override `hashcode()` — the two methods _must_ agree with each other. Two objects that are _equal_ _**must**_ also have the same hashcode.

Comment: But must, 2 objects that have same hashcode, be equals?

Comment: @user3647971 No -- two unequal objects may have the same hashcode, in which case there is a hash collision and they end up in the same bucket. Hash lookup is a quick computation to find the bucket, followed by finding the one item (of possibly many) in that bucket that is actually equal to what you are looking for. Non Java-specific, basic hash algorithm fact. Since hashing reduces a complex infinite data space to a single finite number there _must_ be unequal items where the hashcode collides.

Comment: Tnx all. I ended up overriding the hashCode method of each inner element to return same digit for the same looking values. the hashCode of main class is using the ones related to its subclasses, so it seems working now.

Comment: try overring the `equals` method and defining your own logic which checks for all the values. But see that, `hashCode` is same for the objects that have `equals` value `true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the equals() and hashcode() methods of MyClass.

Your ide can probably do it for you.

What you want is a deep compare. The equals method should go into each list and iterate, and compare.

hashcode should use the hashcode of each element to to generate a hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

Please override the equals method to check for equality. Do not use the hashcode for equality checking.

Please check the java documentation on equals/hashcode, as it is probably too verbose for this post to put the diff. between equals/hashcode and its uses.

In order to compare two Lists, you could simply use the list.equals method... no need to iterate the lists for Ex (Please see java.util.List documentation for equals) ;

```
// Sample Code...
public class MyClass {
    List<OtherClass> myList;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (o instanceof List) {
           myList.equals((List) o) ;
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...